# "[" is not closed ? when I've already closed it

Tags: python

I could input multiple times into a list up to a point using while.
However, I cannot use list comprehension because it said the "[" is not closed.

what works

```
x = int(input('enter the number of numbers you want to enter '))  
    
ans = []

while len(ans) < x:
    i = int(input('enter the number '))
    ans.append(i)
print(ans)
```

what I want to simplify but produce error: `""[" is not closed "`

```
x = input('enter the number of numbers you want to enter')  
ans = [i = input() while len(ans) < x]
```

**#Update2**. This works now. I think because list comprehension does not mean it could assign value with equality signs.

```
x = int(input('enter the number of numbers you want to enter'))  
    
ans = [input() for i in range(int(x))]
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [ask]. I cannot figure out what you are asking about? What programming language is this? What is the exact error message? The only "beginreceive" is a socket method in .NET; your question doesn't look like a .NET question, or a socket question; and your code looks like Python, but isn't (or if it is _supposed_ to be Python, it has many errors). Without the correct tag, we can't even begin to help you. Please tag correctly, and provide as much information as you have.

Comment: It looks like [tag:python].

Comment: Can you retag your question and add the correct code but with loop?

Comment: If it's [tag:python]. I think you can't use while in list comprehension. Can you try to replace it with `[input() for i in range(int(x))]`.

Comment: If that's Python, that code doesn't produce an error related to unclosed brackets. Please show the actual code that can reproduce the error, **and the full error message**.

Comment: sorry for my lack of etiquette, I'm new here. This is python and I was trying to input multiple time into a list without having to do loop and append. Again, I'm sorry for my ignorance and I will learn to ask better.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details and replace the misused tag. I know it is not perfect and will try to ask better. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks

Comment: Note that, even if this were valid **syntax**, it couldn't possibly work: `ans = …` computes some value and **then** assigns it to `ans`, so there's no possibility of checking `len(ans)` _during_ that computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

It seems you are trying to simplify your while loop using a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). However, this simplification produces a syntax error due to two things

1. You cannot assign variables inside list comprehensions with an equality sign - additionally there is no reason to assign here anyway
2. List comprehensions does not work with `while` loops. Instead you can change to using a for loop

Fixing the above two issues, a working solution could be:

```
x = int(input('enter the number of numbers you want to enter '))
ans = [int(input('enter the number ')) for _ in range(x)]
print(ans)
```

Note that the `_` is just a blank placeholder variable as it is not used for anything

Comment: Thanks for re-editting my question and the code. It helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = input('enter the number of numbers you want to enter')  
ans = [int(input()) for i in range(int(x))]
print(ans)
```